# Marionette Nested LayoutView is not rendering, showing error "Element must be exist in DOM"

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

Here is, what I have achieve so far. I am having a div inside my first template.  When I am showing another layoutView inside that div. it is showing the following error.

> **Uncaught Error: An "el" #nestedDiv must exist in DOM**

**HTML -**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>MarionetteJS</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container"><div>

  <script type='text/template' id='myTemplate'>
    <h2><%=heading%></h2>
    <div id='nestedDiv'></div>
  </script>

  <script type='text/template' id='innerTemplate'>
    <h2><%=nestedHeading%></h2>
  </script>

  <script src='_assets/js/_lib/jquery-1.7.2.min.js'></script>
  <script src='_assets/js/_lib/underscore.js'></script>
  <script src='_assets/js/_lib/backbone.js'></script>
  <script src='_assets/js/_lib/backbone.marionette.js'></script>
  <script src='_assets/js/layoutView.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS -

```
//Application Object
var myApp = new Marionette.Application({
  regions: {
    main: '#container'
  }
});

//First Model
var TaskModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    'heading' : 'Welcome to Backbone'
  }
});

//Second Model
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    'nestedHeading' : 'This is a subheading.'
  }
});

//View for Div #nestedDiv
var PersonView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  template: '#innerTemplate'
});


//View for main Region
var TaskView = Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
  template : '#myTemplate',
  onShow: function() {
    var person = new Person();
    var personView = new PersonView({model: person});
    var PersonLayoutView = Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
      regions: {
        'foo' : '#nestedDiv'
      }
    });
    var obj = new PersonLayoutView();
    obj.foo.show(personView);
  }
});


var taskModel = new TaskModel();
var taskView = new TaskView({model:taskModel});
myApp.main.show(taskView);
```

and here is JSBin Link - http://jsbin.com/dusica/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 0):

`onShow` is a callback on the Marionette Region object and cannot be called on the layout directly.

You probably want to:

1 Call render() on the instantiated LayoutView, in order to render the template in the DOM;
 2 Instantiate a new view to show within a Region that was defined on the LayoutView;
 3 Show the view within the region. If you need it, you can use obj.foo.onShow() as a callback after the view was rendered within the region;

According to the docs:

https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.layoutview.md

> interactions with Marionette.Region will provide features such as
>   onShow callbacks, etc. Please see the Region documentation for more
>   information.

https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.region.md

> "show" / onShow - Called on the view instance when the view has been
>   rendered and displayed.
>   "show" / onShow - Called on the region
>   instance when the view has been rendered and displayed.

Sidenote: in case you would be tempted to use onRender() (LayoutView extends from ItemView), don't. onRender does not mean that the view is present in the DOM, but rather that it is prepared for insertion.

Answer (score -1):

That error basically means that your #nestedDiv is not yet in DOM when you are trying to show the view. And that is understandable as you have not showed obj (a PersonLayoutView) in any region.

In fact, you do not need another nested layout view. Consider modifying your view for main region to:

```
//View for main Region
var TaskView = Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
  template : '#myTemplate',
  regions: {
    'personLayoutRegion': '#nestedDiv'
  },
  onShow: function() {
    var person = new Person();
    var personView = new PersonView({model: person});
    this.personLayoutRegion.show(personView);
  }
});
```

It works at: http://jsbin.com/pecoxujose/2/

Comment: the element can be in the actual document but not within marionette for whatever reason.